# Add data to Json by Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, discord.js

I'am trying to put a datas on .Json, but i don't want delete de other content.

```
if (fs.existsSync(`./winloss/${nameid}.json`)){
            fs.writeFileSync(`./winloss/${nameid}.json`, `{
              "name": "0"
             }`)
          };
```

Comment: [https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either:

- Read the content of the JSON file, then parse it, then update the object, and finally overwrite the file writting data from `JSON.stringify` on the object.
- Or, use a NPM package, like this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile